# A six-sided die painted using five colors, at least two opposite sides are not the same color/no pair of opposite sides are the same color.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

A die (six sides, each with a different number on it) is to be painted using five colors.
$(a)$ How many ways are there to do this?
$(b)$ How many ways are there to paint the cube so that at least two
opposite sides are not the same color?
$(c)$ How many ways are there to paint the cube so that no pair of
opposite sides are the same color?

Attempt:

$a)$ $\frac{6!}{5!}$

$b)$ $\frac{6!}{2!2!}$
$c)$ No idea for this one.

Comment: When you say 'using five colors', must all five colors be used?  And when you say 'each with a different number', does that mean that faces are distinguishable?  Regardless, these values are wrong, and there's a clear 'sanity check' that should tell you why; the paintings that match (b) are a subset of the paintings that match (a), so there _have_ to be fewer of them - but if you compute the actual values for your answers to (a) and (b) you'll find that (b) is (much) larger.

Comment: (Incidentally, if you can give not just the values you got, but also _how_ you got those values, it will make it much easier for people to help you.)

Comment: Question 3 and question 2 together kind of imply we don't have to use all 5 colours otherwise they'd have the same answer.

Comment: Your answers to a) and b) seem to be random.

Answer (score 1):

(a) $5$ choices per side, $5^6$

(b) If all opposite sides were the same colour, you'd have $5^3$ choices, so $5^6 - 5^3$ must be the answer.

(c) For each pair of opposite sides, you have $20 = 5 \cdot 4$ choices.  Therefore you have $20^3$ choices for this one.